# cloud vision missing the order of values (row/Column) while reading text with handwritten

Tags: java, ocr, google-cloud-vision, text-recognition, handwriting-recognition

I am reading an image file using cloud vision. My input file is similar to a form. CV reads all the data close to accuracy of handwritten text (including numbers, alphabets). But it misses the order the text stored in the input image. My input image file contains multiple rows. Example. A row will be like  A 86.43  B  232.63  C  empty and so on multiple rows are there. Output become  A B 232.63 C 86.43....  (A B C D... are printed text) And the values next to A B C D are handwritten. Each pair is a combination of Printed, Handwritten.

`Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION` && `Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` both tried.

Any other specific values to be set, in order to maintain the row order strictly ? Anyother  `ImageContext or Feature`  need to be set? I am not set any `ImageContext` as of now.
Input Image is
[image]

Output received was,
Producer:
Crop:
Sample Type: Initial Sample
Source Type: C
Destination:
pint:
Bin No: SONY
Station #:
Specification: TF 3 CWRS 13.4
Represented Tonnes: 540
curan
2021
Lab Testing Fangber
13.4
14.5
33. Stwo
379
WG
TWG
PROT
MST
HVK
MIDG&SWF
FUS
ERG %
3.2
Sev Sprtd
0.5
MIL
TOT SPRTD 0.6
FRST
SHR
FAI.L NBR
DKG
FY1S4
Pre-Inspected
comment (80): 2.5% sex sprld
QC
Comment (Facility): Please Check Grade, Falling Number.
mst 14.7 Px 13.4 Lbs 58.2 Mil 3.3 Sevspts .2
o

Comment: If possible can you provide your input file and the response you get from Vision API? Just so the community can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately Cloud Vision does not have any options on maintaining row order. For now you need to manually parse the response to properly set the order of your rows. You can also file a [feature request to the Vision API team](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) and suggest your idea on row ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Do you think any other api or libraries would do justification for my request as well @RiccoD

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189099533 I have added my request as well.  It seems the issue already pointed out by other developers still they are working on it without any ETA.  Please add your vote and pass it to other Cloud Vision network people for voting, in order to prioritize this fix.